# R - PCA using the 7 features

Tags: r, preprocessor, r-caret

I have my simple prediction. I had 12 possible features. After finding out that most of the variance is caught by 7 of them - I used `preProcess`
from `caret` package - I want to create a linear model `lm` using just these 7 variables.

I ran `preProcess`

`pp <- preProcess(tr_1,thresh = 0.8,method = "pca")`

The result was 
`PCA needed 7 components to capture 80 percent of the variance`

The question is how to run a model/prediction using only these 7 features.

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have done and we can easier help you

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete example on how to select a specific number of `PCA components`. You need to set  `pcaComp = 7`  inside `preProcess` or use `thresh = 0.8`, and then apply your processing to the training and testing data as shown below. `?preProcess` provides more details. If you want to use `PCA` with `train` method to tune a model, read my answer to a similar question in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557524/principal-component-analysis-with-caret). Remember, if you have `categorical variables (factors)`, you need to convert them first to `dummy variables` before you can apply your processing (center, scale, pca, etc.). For more details about creating `dummy variables` read [this](http://topepo.github.io/caret/preprocess.html) on the `caret` website.

```
library(caret)
library(MASS)#for the Boston dataset
data(Boston)

#number of samples and predictors (including the outcome)
dim(Boston)
#predictors names (medv is the response)
names(Boston)

#you can find more about the Boston Dataset
?Boston

#Let's split the the data to train and test sets
set.seed(10457)
train_idx <- createDataPartition(Boston$medv, p = 0.75, list = FALSE)

train <- Boston[train_idx,]
test <- Boston[-train_idx,]

#Now using preProcess, you need to set the pcaComp = 7, or thresh = 0.8
#you may need to center and scale first and then apply PCA
#or just use method = c("pca")

#create the preProc object, remember to exclude the response (medv)
preProc  <- preProcess(train[,-14], 
                       method = c("center", "scale", "pca"),
                       pcaComp = 7) # or thresh = 0.8
#Apply the processing to the train and test data, and add the response 
#to the dataframes
train_pca <- predict(preProc, train[,-14])
train_pca$medv <- train$medv
test_pca <- predict(preProc, test[,-14])
test_pca$medv <- test$medv

#you can verify the 7 comp
> head(train_pca)
        PC1          PC2         PC3        PC4        PC5        PC6       PC7 medv
1 -2.063576  0.784975586  0.42188132 -0.4674029 -0.9208095 -0.1561148  0.2940533 24.0
2 -1.411319  0.605782852 -0.62260611  0.2258748 -0.4840448  0.3235172 0.5061220 21.6
3 -2.052144  0.514495591  0.18221545  0.9539644 -0.8148428  0.4832016 0.3699110 34.7
4 -2.596799 -0.068710981 -0.10115928  1.1308079 -0.4056899  0.6759937 0.4954385 33.4
5 -2.435048  0.032030728 -0.06201039  1.1046487 -0.5043492  0.6176695 0.5808873 36.2
6 -2.187428 -0.007289459 -0.63593163  0.6597568 -0.1828520  0.6043359 0.5659098 28.7

#Now fit your lm model, something like
fit <- lm(medv~., data = train_pca)

> fit$coefficients
(Intercept)         PC1         PC2         PC3         PC4         PC5         PC6         PC7 
 22.3524934  -2.2357451   1.5531484   3.2346456   2.3612132  -1.7321590  -0.4438279  -0.2850688
```

BTW, next time when you ask a question, try to post a reproducible example (code + data), so people can understand the problem and help you.